# Using sails and waterline, where is the showJoins option set when using toObject()?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Using the `Model.toObject()` call , I saw that all association keys were being stripped. Looking through the documentation, it seems there's a `showJoin` option as well as a `joins[]` array of keys to include.

But, I haven't found a place where to send in or set those options. Anyone know?

Comment: not clear as to why you are using Model.toObject ? Waterline will automatically convert the database row to a JSON object. Could you elaborate on what exactly you are trying ?

Comment: this is in overwriting Model.toJSON() - I based my code directly off of documentation

Comment: I have the same problem. When I send the JSON to the client the ids of associations aren't included because the `showJoin` option is apparently not set. (So `toObject` is only used via `toJSON`, but the problem remains.) I'd like to not override these methods but rather just set the flag in the appropriate spot, but I'm still struggling to find where.

Comment: It looks like this might be a related issue: [balderdashy/waterline#308](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/308)